# How to delete nodes from xml file?

Tags: javascript, xml, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I want to manipulate a data from an XML file with Appcelerator's app.

So I'm able to read the information from this xml file with this code:

```
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory,'/XML/file.xml'); 
var xmltext = file.read().text;
var doc = Ti.XML.parseString(xmltext); 
var nodes = doc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("code");
for (var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++) {
    var element = nodes.item(i);
    //LA SECTION CODE DEL SOCIAL HISTORY, DEVE ESSERE
    //29762-2
    if(element.getAttribute('code') == '29762-2'){
        var section = element.parentNode;   
        if(section.nodeName =='section'){
            var entries = section.getElementsByTagName("entry");
        }
    }
}
```

With this code, I can read every node of my XML file.
Now I want to delete some section from this XML file.

How can I do this?

> EDIT

This is the code that I used to remove a child from my XML file.

```
var section = element.parentNode;   
var entries = section.getElementsByTagName("entry");
for(var e=0; e< entries.length; e++){
   var entry = entries.item(e);
   var nodiRimasti = section.removeChild(entry);
}
```

If I try to inspect on a child of section I can see that one node is removed. Now I don't know how can I confirm this modify, then saved the modify the file.

Answer (score 1):

After you've used parseString you get an XML Document which has tons of methods you can use. Look at the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.XML.Document) what you can use.

For example, you can use the `removeChild` method to remove a child element which basically is what you're asking.

Once you've removed it, parse the XML document back to a string and update the file using the [filesystem](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem) API's

Comment: thanks for your answer. I just edit my Question with a code to remove a child. Now I don't know how can I saved the modify