# How can delete nodes from XML file

Tags: javascript, xml, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I'm building an app with Appcelerator that read the information from an Xml file. Then this is ok, works. Now I want to delete some nodes from this file but I'm not able to do this. This is the code that I have build to remove nodes from file:

```
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory,'/XML/file.xml'); 
var xmltext = file.read().text;
var doc = Ti.XML.parseString(xmltext); 
var nodes = doc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("code");
 for (var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++) {
    var element = nodes.item(i);
    if(element.getAttribute('code') == '29762-2'){
        var section = element.parentNode;   
        var entries = section.getElementsByTagName("entry");
        for(var e=0; e< entries.length; e++){
            var entry = entries.item(e);
            var nodiRimasti = section.removeChild(entry);
        }
    }
}
file.write(file,true);
```

If I try to run this code, I don't have never error but the Node is not deleted.

Comment: What is the "entries" variable? It isn't defined here

Comment: @Luca De Nardi, I have just edited my post and I have insert "entries variable"

Comment: you already asked this... don't make a new question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete nodes from xml file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40906232/how-to-delete-nodes-from-xml-file)